# Favourite tags can be overwritten when modifying the list across multiple tabs

Tags: bug, tag-watching

Pretty simple repro:

1. Open multiple tabs on a single site.
2. Add a favourite tag on one tab.
3. Add a different favourite tag on the other tab.
4. The tag added in #2 will be overwritten.